Esoteric meaning of Mahishasura story
With respect to Devi bhagavatam. We see how Devi(Durga) kills Mahishasura.
What’s is esoteric meaning of this? We see Mahishasura sending his generals(explicit names are there) to fight and finally he comes and fight. What’s the hidden meaning of these dramatic episodes(is it just literal) ?

Found this one, if anyone is interested.

This reference is far better, please check.
